# Java Runtime exec() fails to escape characters properly

Tags: java, character-encoding, escaping, exec, runtime.exec

This might already been answered before but that was regarding unicode and I don't think this is unicode (it's in ASCII so...).

When I execute this in my terminal there is no problem what so ever

```
vboxmanage setextradata "Test Machine" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/HostPort" 2222
```

However when I use the following in Java

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("vboxmanage setextradata \"Test Machine\" \"VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/HostPort\" 2222");
```

It returns an error: unregistered vm '"TestMachine"'

The same goes for parameters with spaces in them like Test\ Machine, then it doesn't escape the space.

Now I think this has something to do with the character encoding, but I don't see any option to set that o_O

Comment: doesn't look like an encoding issue. See [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) on how to specify arguments to a program.

Comment: Why would `TestMachine` need to be in quotes or escaped?

Comment: Because this is inside a general function and there is a possibility that there will be VM names with spaces, therefore we need the quotes. I'll change it to make it more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute command with parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134486/how-to-execute-command-with-parameters)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are calling the program and its arguments in one pass, which effectively shoves the entire string into the processing environment (hoping for the best).

In Windows systems, the operating system makes a point of handling the executable and arguments differently, and putting them all in the same string just requires you to pick the perfect string which the environment (of which there are two that i know about) can re-parse into an argument list.  The better solution is to use

```
Runtime.exec(new String[] {"vboxmanage", "setextradata", "Test Machine", "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/HostPort", "2222"});
```

which corresponds to `Runtime's`

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray)
         throws IOException
```

At best, with the one string method you'll eventually find out how to hint and escape out the arguments so they don't get treated as part of the executable name, but then you'll encounter a new issue, that they get passed all as one parameter to the executable.  Once you fix that depending on the environment, you'll either find that your quotes aren't getting stripped from the parameters (leading to parameters like "2222") or that Window's semi-broken argument parsing is going to parse on whitespace first (leading to parameters like ("Test).  It doesn't make sense, that's why there are more than one `exec` methods available.

Comment: Thanks for the great extra explination :)

Comment: Very unfortunately none of the solutions that use the "chunked" interfaces to Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder are applicable in my particular scenario.

I receive the command line as a whole from configuration (coming from the user), and I am supposed to substitute variables in it before executing it. Example: ```sometool -i ${current_file_path}```. It is my responsibility to make sure that the path variable expands to a single and entire command line argument, but I cannot (be bothered to) parse the entire command line so I can feed it to those chunked APIs.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, Runtime.exec(String[]) is unsafe as well. If the argument array contains the empty string, the empty argument is basically omitted which may lead to an invalid command line. Also, quotes within any of the arguments are not prefixed with backslashes. Also, the ProcessBuilder may add quotes to arguments without doubling the number of preceding backslashes which gives funny results if one passes a path to a folder like c:\program files\ including the trailing backslash.

Microsoft's documentation of their command line tokenizer is available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx

The issues I described are documented here:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6468220
and
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6518827

Answer (score 6):

Using `Runtime.exec(String)` is the wrong method for this case (and generally the wrong method for passing arguments to the new process).

**Use [one of the exec overloads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) that takes an array of arguments** to pass to the new process. (Or, see Paul's answer with ProcessBuilder -- neither of these approaches suffer from escaping issues).

Example:

```
exec(new String[] { "vbomanager",
  "setextradata", "Test Machine",
  "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/ssh/HostPort", "2222"});
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Scary, you and I just typed out (almost) the same code sample.  I know it's because it is the "right" answer, but it still took me back for a moment.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than trying to quote the command line you might be better off using `ProcessBuilder.command(arg0, arg1, ...)`

See [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for details.