# unix file creation with java

Tags: java, linux, unix

If I use this command inside unix shell :

```
ls -lrt > ttrr
```

I get my output.

**But when I am putting that command inside a java program then it does not work, it does not give any error, but no file is created after the program execution is complete**.

here is my program :

```
public class sam
   {
       public static void main(String args[])
         {
            try
               {
                 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" ls -lrt > ttrr");
               }
          catch(Exception e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }
   }
```

Comment: Is it some homework question.  why not use Java APIs to create files/directories...

Comment: @Jayan is correct. It suits well for other OS also. Better use java api's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using redirection operators with Java Runtime Exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380054/using-redirection-operators-with-java-runtime-exec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix you need to be aware that the command line is first processed by the shell and then the resulting string being executed. In your case, this command: `ls -lrt > ttrr` has a `>` in it that must be processed by a shell.

When you use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` the `command` string is not processed by a shell and is sent straight to the OS for it to be executed.

If you want your command to be executed properly (I'm talking about `ls -lrt > ttrr`) you have to execute the shell in the same command. in the case of Bash you can use something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "ls -lrt > ttrr"});
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what is really being executed is a command with two arguments: "bash" (the shell program), "-c" a Bash option to execute a script in the command line, and "ls -lrt > ttrr" which is the actual "command" you want to run.