# Call SQLCMD from java 7

Tags: java

I am facing an error executing sqlcmd from Java. My code is below:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                         .exec("sqlcmd -m-1 -S localhost,1433 -d my_server -U sa 
                                -P abc -Q \"select * from Assests where AssetID > 
                                'G123204E4-1234-4A31-B37B-0092D68DA429'\" -k2 -W 
                                -h-1 -s\",\" -o \"D://Assests.csv\"");
```

While running sqlcmd from sqlclient its working fine but from Java it is giving the following expression error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Server SANDEEPB-PC, Line 1 An expression
>   of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is
>   expected, near 'AssetID'.

Yet, when I change ">" to "=", it works fine.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you use JDBC?
Also, looks like AssetID is a varchar, and `>` operator does not make sense as it isn't really deterministic. What exactly is greater than `'G123204E4-1234-4A31-B37B-0092D68DA429'`?

Comment: Try escaping the ">" by using "\>".

Comment: not working escaping the ">" by using "\>"

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the command using the string array version of exec(), see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])
This will properly escape all the arguments.

See [Java Runtime exec() fails to escape characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969724/java-runtime-exec-fails-to-escape-characters-properly)

It should look like this (not tested);

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
    .exec(new String[] {"sqlcmd", "-m", "-1", "-S", "localhost,1433", "-d", "my_server", "-U", "sa", "-P", "abc", "-Q", "select * from Assests where AssetID > 'G123204E4-1234-4A31-B37B-0092D68DA429'", "-k2", "-W", "-h", "-1", "-s", ",\"", "-o", "D://Assests.csv"});
```

for MySQL (tested)

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec(new String[] {"mysql", "-u", "root", "-ppassword","-e", "select 1<2"});
```

Comment: ` .exec("sqlcmd","-m-1", "-S","localhost,1433","-d",....)`
BUT you are already in JAVA, just use JDBC